# How to index a specific array element in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

I want to create a type that combines the values of two properties of one object in an array.

My solution so far, looks like this:

```js
const CONFIGS = [
  { section: "a", name: "1" },
  { section: "b", name: "2" },
] as const;

type ConfigSections<I extends number> = typeof CONFIGS[I]["section"];
type ConfigSectionEntryName<I extends number> = typeof CONFIGS[I]["name"];

// Allows all permutations of section and name: "a_1" | "a_2" | "b_1" | "b_2" :(
// I only want "a_1" | "b_2" 
type CompleteConfigName<I extends number> =
  `${ConfigSections<I>}_${ConfigSectionEntryName<I>}`;
```

But in the type `CompleteConfigName<I extends number>` the `I` seems to allow any number, as the type resolves to `"a_1" | "a_2" | "b_1" | "b_2"`.
But I want to enforce a specific index number `I`, so that the type results to `"a_1" | "b_2"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a mapped type like this:

```
type CompleteConfigName = {
  [K in keyof typeof CONFIGS]: (typeof CONFIGS)[K] extends { 
    section: infer A, name: infer B
  }  
    ? `${A & string}_${B & string}` 
    : never
}[keyof typeof CONFIGS & `${bigint}`]
```

`CompleteConfigName` maps over each element in the tuple to create the string literal. We can index this type with `[keyof typeof CONFIGS & '${bigint}']` to create a union of all elements inside the mapped type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwgeQHIDECSBxAyjAvDAbQCgYYBvGCAU2CgEtwAuGAIgEMWAaGMNgWyrMWARhYwAvpxLlKNek1YAjLj36DWAJjGSiAXRhsIMUJCgBuIpagBPAA5V4IPrYA2VKFTjgAZnQDmSGp45NIEANIwdGAwANZU1iDeMDb2ifDI6Ni6zAAUKVRpiKiYWACU4fpUAB4eYAAmRhTSpNS0DGDMUd5UAE4wAILcvAKdYN19AELS4qTNMAD8MAAGACRk-TAAZJRQPVF+4gD6axNbO3tgB0swc8xgVABuvUTiBHEJSfmFGSVnq2SKfxRKDiJa6IA)